# compute the singular value decomposition of the matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

Looking for some help with the question below, I have given it a try and looking to see if my workings make sense or where I have went wrong. Spent some time trying to figure this out and typing this up in the right format, all help is greatly appreciated!

> compute the singular value decomposition of the matrix
>   $$A= \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\\-1&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Want: $c=U \Sigma V^t$
Using equations:
$$1) C^TC = V \Sigma ^T \Sigma V^T$$
$$2) CV = U \Sigma$$
Starting with Eq$(1)$:
$$C^TC = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\2&1&0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\\-1&0\\\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\2&5\\\end{bmatrix} $$
Finding eigen values and eigen vectors:
$$det(C^T-\lambda I) =\begin{bmatrix}2-\lambda&2\\2&5-\lambda\\\end{bmatrix} = (2-\lambda)(5-\lambda)-4 = \lambda ^2 -7\lambda + 6$$Hence $\lambda_1 = 1 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\\end{bmatrix},  \lambda_2 = 6 \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\1\\\end{bmatrix}$
Then $V = \begin{bmatrix}-2&\frac{1}{2}\\1&1\\\end{bmatrix}$
and $\Sigma= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\sqrt6\\\end{bmatrix}$

Then using Eq$(2)$ $CV = U$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\\-1&0\\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-2&\frac{1}{2}\\1&1\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&2.5\\1&1\\2&-0.5\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Making that unit length and multiplying by $\Sigma$ gives $U$

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{0}{\sqrt2}&\frac{2.5}{2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{2}{\sqrt2}&-\frac{0.5}{\sqrt2}\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\sqrt6\\\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: You should get $V=\frac1{\sqrt5}\pmatrix{-2&1\\1&2}$ so that rows and columns are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @LutzL so where have I went wrong? could you post an answer? I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off $\Sigma$ is of the wrong dimension. Since $C$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix, so should $\Sigma$:

$$\Sigma=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt 6 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Next, you need to normalize $V$:

$$V=\left[\begin{matrix}-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} & \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now, we have:

$$U\Sigma=CV=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & \sqrt 5 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} & \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now, since the above is $U\Sigma$ and the first column of $\Sigma$ is $e_1$, the first column of this matrix must be the first column of $U$. Also, since the second column of $\Sigma$ is $\sqrt 6e_2$, the second column of $U$ must be the second column of $CV$ divided by $\sqrt 6$, so we get:

$$U=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & \sqrt{\frac 5 6} & ?? \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} & \sqrt{\frac 2 {15}} & ?? \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 30} & ??\end{matrix}\right]$$

Finally, since $C$ has rank $2$ but $m=3$ rows, you need to pad the last column of $U$ with an orthogonal vector from the cokernel so that $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. Since the last column is orthogonal to the first two columns, it must be in the null space of the following matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & \frac 1 {\sqrt 5} & \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} \\ \sqrt{\frac 5 6} & \sqrt{\frac 2 {15}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 30}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Basically, I just turned the two columns of $U$ into row vectors of the above matrix so that the null space of the above matrix is orthogonal to the columns of $U$. Now, find the RREF of the above matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$$

From here, it should be clear that $(1,-2,1)^t$ spans the null space of this matrix. However, for $U$ to be orthogonal, we need this to be a unit vector, so normalize it by dividing by $\sqrt 6$:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \\ -\sqrt{\frac 2 3} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Finally, we insert this column into $U$ to get:

$$U=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & \sqrt{\frac 5 6} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} & \sqrt{\frac 2 {15}} & -\sqrt{\frac 2 3} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt 5} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 30} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: how did you get that V? where did I go wrong?

Comment: @jh123 You forgot to normalize the vectors in $V$. $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, so the columns need to be unit vectors. I divided by $\sqrt 5$ in order to turn these columns into unit vectors.

Comment: my V is different then yours tho, how did you get those entries?

Comment: if you could show how to pad the last column I could accept the answer, I think I got a little messed up in my solution! I have never seen that method before

Comment: @jh123 I have added how to find the last column of $U$ in the answer above. Does this make sense now?

Comment: yes that makes sense, I now have $\Sigma , V^T, U$ which completes my question. I will accept it now! one last question, in a comment above LutL said that in matrix V the rows and columns are orthogonal to each other, so in position a21 he has 1 while you have 2?

Comment: @jh123 Sorry about that; $V_{21}$ should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$. That was just a typo. I have fixed my answer above.

Comment: okay so everything else looks correct then? thanks for your time, I will now learn your method

Comment: did I calculate my eigen values correctly? I guess I calculated my eigen vectors wrong

Comment: @jh123 OK, I just double-checked my answer and I think everything else is good. Also, actually, you calculated the eigenvalues correctly: It should be $1$ and $\sqrt 6$. The mistake you made is that you made $\Sigma$ of the wrong dimension: It should be a $3\times 2$ matrix, not just a $2\times 2$.

Comment: okay I see what I did wrong then! so I guess to check if it correct I would have to multiply those 3 matrices to see if it equals A?

Comment: Yes, to check your answer, you need to make sure $U$ times $\Sigma$ times $V^T$ is the same as $C$.

Comment: great well it looks like you have the correct answer, thanks for everything!